# Solaris 11 / Illumos / OmniOS: Which package has /usr/include/sys/types.h?

Tags: c, 64-bit, solaris, libc

The [Ubuntu equivalent](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=492245) would be `libc6-dev`, but I can't seem to find it for Solaris?

How can I get types.h and related files for building packages on Solaris or Illumos?

Comment: 5 years later, I had the same problem, except this time on OmniOS/Illumos instead of Solaris. lol! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41841143/trouble-installing-compiled-perl-module-on-omnios-illumos-types-h-is-missing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the system/header package.

I found this via http://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/release/en/search.shtml?token=types.h&action=Search

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you use IPS 'pkg search 'types.h''

The [Oracle Solaris 11 Cheat Sheet for Image Packaging System](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/documentation/ips-one-liners-032011-337775.pdf) could be useful, too.