# Trouble installing compiled Perl module on OmniOS / Illumos - types.h is missing

Tags: perl, gcc, module, compiler-errors, installation

I'm running OmniOS r151020 which is the current stable release. Decided to install some Perl modules. I'm installing them in a custom libraries directory. Here is how I'm installing.

```
sudo pkg install gnu-tar gnu-make gcc51
export MAKE=gmake
mkdir /bailey/lib/perl; cd /bailey/lib/perl
ln -s perl5/lib/perl5 cpan # so that my apps can add /bailey/lib/perl/cpan to their @INC
curl -L https://cpanmin.us | perl - App::cpanminus --local-lib=/bailey/lib/perl/perl5 # installs cpanm
perl5/bin/cpanm --local-lib=/bailey/lib/perl/perl5 local::lib && eval $(perl -I /bailey/lib/perl/cpan -Mlocal::lib) # sets default installation dir
perl5/bin/cpanm Crypt::Eksblowfish::Bcrypt
```

Unfortunately, the last command, which is to install a natively compiled module, results in an error:
**`/usr/perl5/5.16.1/lib/i86pc-solaris-thread-multi-64int/CORE/perl.h:610:24: fatal error: sys/types.h: No such file or directory`**

Full transcript:

```
george@bedford:/bailey/lib/perl$ perl5/bin/cpanm Crypt::Eksblowfish::Bcrypt
--> Working on Crypt::Eksblowfish::Bcrypt
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/Z/ZE/ZEFRAM/Crypt-Eksblowfish-0.009.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Crypt-Eksblowfish-0.009 ... OK
Building and testing Crypt-Eksblowfish-0.009 ... FAIL
! Installing Crypt::Eksblowfish::Bcrypt failed. See /home/george/.cpanm/work/1485301763.12637/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
george@bedford:/bailey/lib/perl$ more /home/george/.cpanm/work/1485301763.12637/build.log
cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.7042 on perl 5.016001 built for i86pc-solaris-thread-multi-64int
Work directory is /home/george/.cpanm/work/1485301763.12637
You have make /usr/gnu/bin/make
You have /usr/bin/wget
You have /usr/gnu/bin/tar, /usr/bin/gzip and /usr/bin/bzip2
You have /usr/bin/unzip
Searching Crypt::Eksblowfish::Bcrypt () on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on Crypt::Eksblowfish::Bcrypt
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/Z/ZE/ZEFRAM/Crypt-Eksblowfish-0.009.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking Crypt-Eksblowfish-0.009.tar.gz
Entering Crypt-Eksblowfish-0.009
Checking configure dependencies from META.json
Checking if you have warnings 0 ... Yes (1.13)
Checking if you have strict 0 ... Yes (1.07)
Checking if you have Module::Build 0.38 ... Yes (0.39_01)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::Install 1.46 ... Yes (1.58)
Configuring Crypt-Eksblowfish-0.009
Running Build.PL
Created MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Creating new 'Build' script for 'Crypt-Eksblowfish' version '0.009'
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have warnings 0 ... Yes (1.13)
Checking if you have XSLoader 0 ... Yes (0.16)
Checking if you have parent 0 ... Yes (0.225)
Checking if you have Exporter 0 ... Yes (5.66)
Checking if you have Carp 0 ... Yes (1.26)
Checking if you have Test::More 0 ... Yes (0.98)
Checking if you have strict 0 ... Yes (1.07)
Checking if you have Class::Mix 0.001 ... Yes (0.005)
Checking if you have MIME::Base64 2.21 ... Yes (3.13)
Checking if you have Module::Build 0 ... Yes (0.39_01)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::CBuilder 0.15 ... Yes (0.280206)
Building and testing Crypt-Eksblowfish-0.009
Building Crypt-Eksblowfish
gcc -I/usr/perl5/5.16.1/lib/i86pc-solaris-thread-multi-64int/CORE -DXS_VERSION="0.009" -DVERSION="0.009" -fPIC -c -D_REENTRANT -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_TS_ERRNO -DPTR_IS_LONG -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -D_LARGEFILE_
SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -O3 -o lib/Crypt/Eksblowfish.o lib/Crypt/Eksblowfish.c
In file included from lib/Crypt/Eksblowfish.xs:3:0:
/usr/perl5/5.16.1/lib/i86pc-solaris-thread-multi-64int/CORE/perl.h:610:24: fatal error: sys/types.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error building lib/Crypt/Eksblowfish.o from 'lib/Crypt/Eksblowfish.c' at /usr/perl5/5.16.1/lib/ExtUtils/CBuilder/Base.pm line 177.
-> FAIL Installing Crypt::Eksblowfish::Bcrypt failed. See /home/george/.cpanm/work/1485301763.12637/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
george@bedford:/bailey/lib/perl$
```

There does exist a `types.h` file in `/usr/include/net-snmp`. How can I reconcile this difference between the compilation requirements and my system environment. Should I symlink the `types.h` file to exist where the compiler is looking for it? How can I do this, or is there a better option?

Comment: Is this the right site to ask this question, or should I ask on UNIX & Linux?

Comment: I'd say it's on-topic in both, but I don't know which one might yield better answers, if any. Perlmonks might be good, or irc.perl.org as this is quite specific. Have you looked at cpantesters for that module?

Comment: I'm not familiar with OmniOS, but It looks like sys/types.h is in the `system/header` package (at least, it's listed in the [manifest](http://pkg.omniti.com/omnios/r151020/manifest/0/system%2Fheader@0.5.11%2C5.11-0.151020%3A20161230T213755Z)).

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/q/8773535

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, Please post as an answer! Thanks!

Comment: Since OmniOS is an OpenSolaris derivative, maybe you could just tweak your earlier question to mention it too. Not sure we need a separate question about sys/types.h for every distro based on Solaris.

Comment: Oh my! I duplicated my own question. So sorry about that!